# Way to build a querystring in obj-c that escapes as necessary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, query-string

I want to build a querystring in obj-c eg http://myurl.com/myservice?key=value&key2=value2

Just wondering how to go about doing this so that all the unfriendly characters (eg &, %) get escaped properly?

Thanks

Comment: Is it something to do with NSString's stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?

Comment: Or CFURL's CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes? This one looks like a complicated way to do it.

Comment: Found this: http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work?

```
+(NSString*)urlEscape:(NSString *)unencodedString {
    NSString *s = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
        (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
        NULL,
        (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [s autorelease]; // Due to the 'create rule' we own the above and must autorelease it
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but why not just do this? `[unencodedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: I've heard that that function is buggy and doesn't escape eg ampersands. Happy to be proven wrong however, as it does look a lot simpler!

Comment: Heard where, and buggy in what sense?  `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is a convenience Objective-C wrapper for `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` that handles simple transformations. The method-level docs explicitly state: "See CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes for more complex transformations." It looks to me like the URL you're encoding doesn't require that, though.

Comment: I simply want the standard escaping really. I just found in my googling that people said stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding didn't escape ampersands, which i count as essential when escaping!

Comment: Check it out yourself in the debugger in xcode: it doesn't escape ampersands:      (gdb) po [@"a bc&def<>" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:4]
a%20bc&def%3C%3E

Comment: Why would you expect ampersand to be escaped by default, and not forward slash, colon, etc.? They're all reserved characters.